# How to bind inner html to angular1 elements with ng-bind attribute

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

```html
<div ng-bind="model">
  <div>inner html</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to display the inner div? Seems the ng-bind directive will always rewrite div element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-bind will always print what is in the model.
You can do the following thing:

```
<div>
    <div ng-bind="model"></div>
    <div>inner html</div>
</div>
```

Either you can do something like:

```
//JS
app.controller("nameController", function($sce) {
   model = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>inner html</div>");
});

//HTML
<div ng-bind-html="model"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it works for me. But always use html in js code l will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: `//JS
app.controller("nameController", function($sce) {
   model = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div ng-bind='v'></div><div>inner html</div>");
});

//HTML
<div ng-bind-html="model"></div>`